# How to use FieldInfo.SetValue and GetValue properly?

Tags: c#

I am making an automatic saving and loading system that uses attributes. Inside my attribute, I have a method called SetSpecificField, which is supposed to do exactly that. It looks like this:

```
public static bool SetSpecificField(string className, string variableName, AutoLType autoLType)
{
    bool worked = false;
    try
    {
        worked = true;
        foreach (Type type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
        {
            if(type.GetCustomAttribute<AutoLoadEnabled>(true) != null)
            {
                if(type.Name == className)
                {
                    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in type.GetProperties())
                    {
                        if (prop.Name == variableName)
                        {
                            prop.SetValue(autoLType.Value.GetType(), autoLType.Value);
                        }
                    }
                    foreach(FieldInfo field in type.GetFields())
                    {
                        if(field.Name == variableName)
                        {
                            field.SetValue(autoLType.Value.GetType(), autoLType.Value)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        worked = false;
    }

    return worked;
}
```

However it is giving me this error: `ArgumentException: Field aloadBeg defined on type SaveManager is not a field on the target object which is of type System.RuntimeType.` I dont know if I am doing this right. If I am doing this wrong can someone show me how to do it properly?

---

EDIT:
Here is the AutoLType class:

```
public class AutoLType
{
    public static implicit operator AutoSType(AutoLType l)
    {
        if (l.PropertyOrField == PropOrField.Field)
        {
            return new AutoSType(l.Name, l.Value, l.Attribute, AutoSType.PropOrField.Field);
        }
        else
        {
            return new AutoSType(l.Name, l.Value, l.Attribute, AutoSType.PropOrField.Prop);
        }
    }

    public enum PropOrField
    {
        Prop,
        Field
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public AutoLoad Attribute { get; set; }
    public PropOrField PropertyOrField { get; set; }
        
    public AutoLType(string name, object value, AutoLoad attr, PropOrField propOrField)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
        Attribute = attr;
        PropertyOrField = propOrField;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first argument of `SetValue()` must be the object you want to change, not a `System.Type` instance.

Comment: Reflection is "usually" not the right answer for your problem. Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of what you are trying to do. There might be several libraries which can be used to serialize/deserialize objects, no need to write one yourself.

Comment: does `field` correspond to a static or non-static member variable?

Comment: In terms of the assignment in compiled C# source code: `(someObject as someBaseClassOrInterface).someField = someValue` how would you call your `SetSpecificField` function to do the same assignment -- what would you pass for your arguments `className`, `variableName`, `autoLType`?

Comment: @BenVoigt field can refer to both static and non-static variables. className would be automatically given the name of the class that a variable is found in (dont exactly know how to get it from a FieldInfo) variableName would automatically be given the name of the Field using FieldInfo.Name. AutoLType would be given the a instance of the class that I just added to the post.